# How to render AdaptiveCard in ReactNative correctly?

Tags: node.js, react-native, adaptive-cards

I'm using React Native and trying to replicate the StockUpdate card from here [Example Adaptive Cards](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-adaptivecards/)

[Currently Rendered Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ixR.png)

How do I set the correct HostConfig? I believe the rendering is off because the config isn't setup correctly.